# using custom command-line arguments with npm-version

Tags: npm, npm-version

I would like to be able to pass custom command-line arguments when I call npm-version, such that those arguments are available to a 'preversion' script that is automatically run by npm-version.  For example:

`npm version patch -- -s "string" -d`

The purpose is to allow whomever is running npm-version to specify certain values (a release summary and whether the release should be a draft or not); the preversion script then takes those values and updates attributes in the project files before the commit, and those attributes are then used to affect a GitHub release workflow.

Running the above command throws a usage error.  Is there an alternative to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I realize the project files could just be manually edited with the attribute info before running `npm version`, but I'm trying to automate this as much as possible.